# Scenario outlines use multiply threads

Tags: multithreading, junit, parallel-processing, cucumber

I use JUnit5 and Cucumber in my tests. When running the tests in parallel, everything works as I want, but when it comes to the Scenario outline, the examples create additional threads. That is, if I set cucumber.execution.parallel.config.fixed.parallelism=4, the scenarios will run in 4 threads, but when they get to the Examples scenario, 1 additional thread is created for each example. How can I run a parallelism of exactly the scenarios and not the feature files? Or make the feature with scenario outline run one by one?

My junit-platform.properties

```
cucumber.publish.quiet=true
cucumber.execution.parallel.enabled=true
cucumber.execution.parallel.config.strategy=fixed
cucumber.execution.parallel.config.fixed.parallelism=4
```

Answer (score 0):

A scenario outline is not a single scenario. It is multiple scenarios written in a compact form. When an outline is processed by cucumber it generates a standard scenario for each set of examples. Each example is going to run in its own thread.